# React Drawer Navigation Unable to toggle back if gesture swipe is disabled

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-drawer

Please Help I am working on React navigation drawer, if I disable the gesture swipe I am able to toggle the drawer by using navigation.toggleDrawer() function , but once the drawer open unable to toggle it back.
As Per my understanding the drawer Overlay over the Content is preventing the toggle button click event from happening.
if swipe is enabled then clicking at any position outside the drawer is closing the drawer.

**I want to add a button outside the drawer , where i want to achieve click functionality but click event of the button is not happening due to drawer overlay.
How can I achieve this.**

Comment: Have you tried setting `zIndex` on the button and the drawer?

Comment: yes i did tried that @SagarShakya